# Unable to set "spark.driver.maxResultSize" in Spark 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-3.0

I am trying to convert a spark dataframe into a pandas dataframe. I have a sufficiently large driver. I am trying to set the `spark.driver.maxResultSize` value , like this

```
spark = (
        SparkSession
        .builder
        .appName('test')
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize","0")
        .getOrCreate()
    )
```

But the job is failing with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of XXXX tasks (1026.4 MiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MiB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 3.0.0, your error is triggered by [this piece of code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3fdfce3120f307147244e5eaf46d61419a723d50/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSetManager.scala#L677-L690):

```scala
  /**
   * Check whether has enough quota to fetch the result with `size` bytes
   */
  def canFetchMoreResults(size: Long): Boolean = sched.synchronized {
    totalResultSize += size
    calculatedTasks += 1
    if (maxResultSize > 0 && totalResultSize > maxResultSize) {
      val msg = s"Total size of serialized results of ${calculatedTasks} tasks " +
        s"(${Utils.bytesToString(totalResultSize)}) is bigger than ${config.MAX_RESULT_SIZE.key} " +
        s"(${Utils.bytesToString(maxResultSize)})"
      logError(msg)
      abort(msg)
      false
    } else {
      true
    }
  }
```

As you can see, if `maxResultSize == 0` you will never get the error you're getting. [A bit higher](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3fdfce3120f307147244e5eaf46d61419a723d50/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSetManager.scala#L67), you see that `maxResultSize` comes from `config.MAX_RESULT_SIZE`. And that one is finally defined by `spark.driver.maxResultSize` in [this piece of code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3fdfce3120f307147244e5eaf46d61419a723d50/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/config/package.scala#L1190-L1194):

```scala
  private[spark] val MAX_RESULT_SIZE = ConfigBuilder("spark.driver.maxResultSize")
    .doc("Size limit for results.")
    .version("1.2.0")
    .bytesConf(ByteUnit.BYTE)
    .createWithDefaultString("1g")
```

#### Conclusion

You are trying the correct thing! Having `spark.driver.maxResultSize` equal to 0 also works in Spark 3.0. As you see in your error message, it seems that your `config.MAX_RESULT_SIZE` is still equal to the default value of `1024MB`.

This means that your configuration is probably not coming through somehow. I would investigate your whole setup. How are you submitting your application? What is your master? Is your `spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled` config coming through?

Comment: I am running it from a jupyter notebook that submits the job in a kubernetes cluster

Comment: Where are you defining your kubernetes configurations? Like `spark.kubernetes.container.image` or `spark.kubernetes.namespace`? Also, where are you defining your master? I feel like you'll need to add the `spark.driver.maxResultSize` configuration next to those configs (but it's hard to say without knowing your setup properly).